# Thread.Abort () causing application to kill

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winforms

I am developing a wpf application which displays wait dialog to users if some lengthy work is going on. I have created wait dialog as a windows form inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Form. When user change some settings and apply, I display this waitdialog and let application validate and save the new configurations. To display this dialog I create a thread and invoke a method which in-turn call ShowDialog() method of waitdialog form. When settings are validated and saved, I need to hide/disapper this waitdialog form. So, Thread.Abort() is used to abort the thread which displays the waitdialog.

This way, when user clicks on Apply Button to save the new configurations, wait dialog displays and hide properly and a message box is shown if user made wrong entries. Now if user clicks on apply button again, application displays an unhandled exception messagebox stating "Thread was being aborted." To solve this issue, I have used the following:

1- Put Thread.Abort() statement in try/catch block.

2- Used Thread.ResetAbort() statement inside catch block.

3- Subscribed different events on application startup:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += new EventHandler<System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs>(CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException);
this.DispatcherUnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

Still I am unable to eat that exception. Please suggest some way to get rid of the issue. As it causes a weired exception and kill the application.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Wow. `Thread.Abort` to hide a form? Why don't you just use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` and then call `Close` or `Hide`?

Comment: Don't use Thread.Abort()... I would recommend to use Tasks with cancellation token instead of Threads directly...

Comment: `Thread.Abort()` should really be named `Thread.CreateNastyBug()`...

Comment: This is just backwards, you continue processing on the main thread, and launch the dialog on a separate thread using ShowDialog?

Comment: @JamesB: Yes, I continue the processing on the main thread and launch the dialog on the separate thread.

Comment: @himanshu Standard practice for long running operations is to show the dialog on the main thread using show dialog, this suspends interaction with the non-modal UI in a nice way. The processing should be done in the second thread.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I have used Close(). It works, but sometimes it keeps alive "Please Wait.." dialog for few seconds. While it was expected to be closed or disappear instantly.

Comment: You don't need a Thread and thus no Abort() either. Use a Timer. That 'few seconds' delay is a separate problem, we don't have enough info.

Comment: Using Thead.Abort to close a form is a bit like stopping your car by driving it into a tree. It achieves the desired result but leaves your app in a mess.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have approached it.
put the call to the wait dialog in a method eg

```
FORMWAITDIALOG _waitDialog=new FORMWAITDIALOG();
   void ShowDialog(){
        Thread t = new Thread(()=>{
        Invoke(new Action(()=>
        {
        _waitDialog.show();
        }));
        });
        t.start();
     }
```

and then in the click event of the validate button call this method

then in the exit method call `_waitDialog.hide();`